# MongoDB - How to compare fields of different collections in $match of aggregate?

Tags: mongodb

Let's suppose I have the collection `A` and the collection `B`. My query is like following:

```
db.A.aggregate([
    {
       $lookup: {
           from: "B",
           localField: "_id",
           foreignField: "custom_id",
           as: "B"
        }
    },
    {
     $match: {
           "B.anotherId": "A.anotherId" // not working, is it possible?
    }
])
```

I'm curious to know if it's possible to do what I tried to do in `$match`. The goal is to get only the documents that have the same "anotherId" value in A and B documents. Is it supported? And if yes, how do to it?

Comment: post your sample documents for both collections and expected result,

Comment: @turivishal the $lookup part is okay, _id is the local field (A) and custom_id is the foreign field (B). "anotherId" is just another field in both the collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$lookup with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup),

- `let` to define your both fields, and check expression condition in `$match` and `$and`

```
db.A.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "B",
            let: {
                custom_id: "$_id",
                anotherId: "$anotherId"
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: ["$$custom_id", "$custom_id"] },
                                { $eq: ["$$anotherId", "$anotherId"] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "B"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: this will filter and give you just the matches in B @Bob. The same what the $filter would do in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. $lookup provides an array of values. Are you trying to filter the array? Which would mean you have to use $filter.
However, based on your question of how to compare two fields, you have to use $expr.

```
{
     $match: {
        $expr: {
            $eq: ["$firstField", "$secondField"]
       }
    }
}
```

If however you are trying to filter the collection B based on a value in A, you will have to use $filter

```
{
   $set: {
      B: {
         $filter: {
             input: "$B",
             as: "b",
             cond: {
                $eq: ["$A.anotherId", "$$b.anotherId"]
             }
         }
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can I use A.fieldInADocument instead of $firstField and B.fieldInBDocument instead of $secondField?

Comment: I mean, in my case would be: $eq: ["B.anotherId": "A.anotherId"]?

Comment: Your need looks more like a $filter of B rather than a direct match. suppose B has more than one value of "anotherId" in A, then the match with $expr will just return A with all the values in B. And if B does not have a match then $expr will result in no results.
$filter is the way to go to filer B with matches. If you can create a sample of documents in A and B and your expected results, it will help.